# Creating multiple pandas column from combination of a list in python

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas data frame with one column as string seperated with commas

eg:

```
col1     col2
B1,B2,B3 20
B4,B5,B6 15
```

and I want to create another data frame with combination like:

```
Col1     Col2  col3    col4  col5 
B1,B2,B3  20   B1,B2  B2,B3  B1,B3
B4,B5,B6  15   B4,B5, B5,B6  B4,B6
```

How can I do this in Pandas.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It seems your problem needs to be better defined. Does the number differ between rows or input data frames, e.g., is `B1,B2,B3,B4,B5` possible? If so, what is the expected outcome? All distributed in groups of two elements or all subgroups such as `B1, B3, B4`? What should happen if one row has five elements and the other three, what should go into the empty cells? Is there any rule on the order of the subsets to columns or does it not matter what each column contains?

Comment: Do you know that there are always three comma-separated items on the lists of column 1? If not, what's the expected behaviour of there are more items or the number of items is different in different rows?

Comment: Yes it will always be comma-separated and each row will have same number of item. there are different scenario in which it might be four element like B1,B2,B3,B4. I am subsetting Data Frame based on number of item and then putting combination of Two in a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are always 3 values in *col1*, you could use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations
splits = df['col1'].str.split(',', expand=True).values.tolist()
df[['col3', 'col4', 'col5']] = [[','.join(c) for c in combinations(split, 2)] for split in splits]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
       col1  col2   col3   col4   col5
0  B1,B2,B3    20  B1,B2  B1,B3  B2,B3
1  B4,B5,B6    15  B4,B5  B4,B6  B5,B6
```

A more general solution is to do:

```
from itertools import combinations
splits = df['col1'].str.split(',').values.tolist()
rows = [[','.join(c) for c in combinations(split, 2)] for split in splits]
length = max(len(row) for row in rows)

new_cols = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=[f'col{i}' for i in range(3, length + 3)])
res = pd.concat((df, new_cols), axis=1)

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
       col1  col2   col3   col4   col5
0  B1,B2,B3    20  B1,B2  B1,B3  B2,B3
1     B4,B5    15  B4,B5   None   None
```

Note that the input for the second example was:

```
col1     col2
B1,B2,B3 20
B4,B5    15
```